# file_get_contents() "failed to open stream: Permission denied" in Apache server

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents, permission-denied, network-share

Im trying to read a file in a shared network folder which i can reach but php doesnt have access to.

The shared folder "xtern" is located on computer "saturn" and the file is called "seq_ws.csv".

here is my code:

```
<?php 
$fileURL = "\\saturn\xtern\seq_ws.csv";
$fileAvailable = file_exists($fileURL);

if($fileAvailable){
    echo "Succes";
}else{
    echo "fail";
    echo file_get_contents($fileURL);
}
?>
```

which results in the following;

```
fail
Warning: file_get_contents(\saturn\xtern\seq_ws.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\file.php on line 9
```

The strange thing is that i can open the path in both a browser and windows explorer just fine and read the file. The shared folder has all permissions for the user I run Apache on aswell as all permissions for "Everyone".

I have tried researching this problem but havent been able to find any solution. I have checked `php.ini` and `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On`. Im pretty sure it is a setting within Apache, PHP or the shared folder somewhere since i can read the file as stated before but just not with my PHP script.

If anybody has any information or suggestion it would be gladly appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well your if...else condition would have told you that the file path doesn't exist. Why do you try to get the contents in your else/fasly condition? I would verify the path you are using is accurate from the context of your script. Can you include your file structure?

Comment: Your logic is screwy...you're checking if the file exists, and then if it **doesn't** exist, you tell the code to try and read it!

Comment: @segFault i echo the `file_get_contents` as an easy way to get the error message from PHP, the file path is correct since i can open it outside of php and i checked it very often. If the file path is correct i would get a `Failed to open stream : No such file or directory.` error message.

Comment: @ADyson as stated in my last comment which i was writing when you submitted your comment im doing that purely to see the error message from PHP, ill make it more clear in the question.

Comment: Also what's with the four backslashes (\\\\ )? A UNC file share path should start with two backslashes not four

Comment: @ADyson if i use two backslashes it cant find the path in FireFox cause it will only detect one and give me `no such file` error, if i use 4 it detects 2. I dont think this causes any problem.

Comment: How is what Firefox does relevant to your PHP? Perhaps some escaping is going on. Try using two in the PHP, regardless of how a browser behaves. Two is the correct format.

Comment: @ADyson with two backslashes `$fileURL = "\\ssk-desktop\users\test\test.csv";` i get `Warning: file_get_contents(\ssk-desktop\users\test\test.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well I'd say that's more like what you would expect, given the way the program logic is written

Comment: @ADyson but the path/file is valid as i mention in the question, the problem is i dont have permission not that the path is incorrect.

Comment: @ADyson but if i use the "correct" path then why do i get no such file?

Comment: I don't know. I can't see your environment.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question with more info. Like i said the folder share properties are open for "Everyone" and if i put the path in my browser it opens it perfectly.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is not enough, how about: `open_basedir` which keeps paths that allowed separated by semicolon?

Comment: @num8er should it say `open_basedir = \\saturn\xtern` in php.ini then?

Comment: @LifeofMadness yes

Comment: @num8er i changed `open_basedir = \\saturn\xtern` in the php.ini and restarted Apache, now when i run the file i get `Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Apache24\htdocs\file.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (\\saturn\xtern) in Unknown on line 0` any idea why? maybe it needs a `;` in the php.ini ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much more searching of this problem I finally found the answer, the problem with a UNC path is that the Apache service cant get into shared folders on default(maybe its a bug) cause of the way the service is set up. To fix this problem you gotta link Apache to a user profile, I dont know if this is only a problem in Windows.

To fix fix Apache not being able to access shared folders:

1. Go to your local services in Windows `services.msc`
2. Right-click on the Apache service and select properties.
3. Click the "Log on" tab
4. Change the "Log on as:" setting from `Local System account` to `This account` and fill in a account name and password

If you dont want to keep the same account as your `Localhost` to connect to the shared folder just duplicate the name and password into the textboxes.

I hope this will help others that encounter the same problem as I did. While researching this i found many people that did and many diffrent comments/answers but nothing worked.